# Prove or disprove if G is an abelian and H is a normal subgroup of G,then H must be a cyclic

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

$G$ is an abelian group,so every subgroup of an abelian group is normal and:
$$o(H)|o(G)$$
$G$ is an abelian group:$$\forall a,b:ab=ba$$
$H$ is a normal subgroup:$$\forall g \in G,\forall h \in H: ghg^{-1} \in H$$
$$and$$
$$gH=Hg$$
I need to show there is a generator in H,how?
$$$$Thanks.

Comment: $H$ is not necessarily cyclic. As you noted, every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, and there is no reason for every subgroup to be cyclic.

Comment: Why did you decide to "prove" rather than "disprove"?

Comment: @LeeMosher because I don't fully understand this subject so I try to find a counterexample but quickly I go back to the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every group $G$ is a normal subgroup of itself, so this would imply that every abelian group is cyclic.

$\mathbb R$ with addition is a counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

Any subgroup of an abelian group is normal. So to find a counterexample, you could take any non-cyclic subgroup of any abelian group.

For instance, $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is an abelian group, and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ is an acyclic normal subgroup.

Comment: Why $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is an abelian group and why  $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z \times \{0\} $ is an acyclic normal subgroup?

Comment: The direct product of abelian groups is always abelian, which should be easy to see if you know what the direct product is. Consider $(2,3,0)$: if it is generated by some $(x,y,0)$, then $(2,3,0)$ is a scalar multiple of $(x,y,0)$, i.e. there is some integer $c$ such that $(cx,cy,0)=(2,3,0)$. Thus, we must have either $(x,y,0)=(2,3,0)$, or $(x,y,0)=(-2,-3,0)$. But in neither case can $(x,y,0)$ generate $(1,1,0)$, so the group cannot be cyclic. As mentioned, any subgroup of an abelian group is normal.